# Unable to click on Calendar day

Tags: selenium, date, selenium-webdriver, automation, calendar

After open the calendar on multiple destinations options, I can't click on the date.

I get the error: **element click intercepted**

I'm using this method below to get another day different of actual day on calendar:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='tc-datepicker hbox MdDatepickerInput']/span)[2]")).click();

    List<WebElement> dateMultiple1 = driver
            .findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='tc-datepicker-wrapper']//div[@class='td tc-day only-one-selected tc-day-canhover']"));

    for (int i = 0; i < dateMultiple1.size(); i++) {

        String text = dateMultiple1.get(i).getText();
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("23")) {
            dateMultiple1.get(i).click();
            break;
        }
```

The calendar is from multiple destinations option. It's not from round trip date and one way.

It's the WebSite: https://www.turismocity.com.br/

Can you guys help me, please ?

[MultipleDestinationsCalendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12oRD.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An element might be overlaying your element invoke click directly.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",  dateMultiple1.get(i));
```

Comment: Hi arundeep! How can I write it ? I wrote like it: for (int i = 0; i < dateMultiple1.size(); i++) {

   String text = dateMultiple1.get(i).getText();
   if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("23")) {
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",  dateMultiple1.get(i));
    //dateMultiple1.get(i).click();
    break;
   }

But I got that method execute_script is undefined

Comment: Here I fixed it.

Comment: Awesome!!! It works now !!! Thanks a lot, Arundeep. I'm so grateful !!!

Comment: I'm trying Upvoting but I got the message that I can't because I have less than 15 reputation.